# If Date Exist Update Or Insert Sql C#

Tags: c#, mysql

This is my database design

Id          Date        Data_1        Data_1a      Data_2       Data_2a

I want to add new data with combobox select. Im using

```
         if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                datacolumn = "Data_1";
                datacountcolumn = "Data_1a";
            }
            if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                datacolumn = "Data_2";
                datacountcolumn = "Data_2a";
            }
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Info (Date ,"+datacolumn+","+ datacountcolumn +") values ('" + date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + datacount.ToString() + "')";
```

I want to control date if date exist, It must be update the data.
Example Database is

```
 - Id              1 
 - Date            3.5.2017 
 - Data_1          Product1 
 - Data_1a         500 
 - Data_2 
 - Data_2a
```

I want to add new data with Data_2 and Data_2a when 3.5.2017
New Table must be

```
- Id              1 
- Date            3.5.2017 
- Data_1          Product1 
- Data_1a         500 
- Data_2          Product2
- Data_2a         300
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection. You should fix this before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I would also urge to read up about normalization. What you have here appears to be in serious need of normalization. This is clear when you have repeating groups like this. Consider how painful it would be if you need to add Data_3. You would have to change all of your code everywhere. These should be rows, not columns.

Comment: @SeanLange Im newbie in mysql. I am looking for parameterized queries. 
You are quite right.I'm having trouble writing code. But I didnt understand why not columns. Why it should be rows ? I want to add product with date. If database have date. I want to update it.

Comment: You are having problems writing queries because the data structure is not normalized. There are other issues here for sure. Seems your "Date" column is character data, it should be datetime. And Data_1, is that a ProductName? Data_1a is maybe the price? I can help you create a better structure but I don't understand what this data is.

Comment: I added all columns (except id increasing auto) are text. Data_1a is count. Product count example product1 count is 500

Comment: No offense but this is just an awful way to build your database. You need to use proper datatypes (dates, integers, etc). Unless this is the main product table (which I doubt) you need to have relational data that is not the name because that could change.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? Please don't spam tags.